# Deserializing data form a SQL Database

Tags: sql, haskell, hdbc

I've a little application, backed by a database (SQLite, but it's not really relevant to the question). I've defined some types like:

```hs
data Whatever = Whatever Int Int String String
data ImportantStuff = ImportantStuff { id :: Int, count :: Int, name :: String, description :: String }
```

The types are mapped to tables in the DB. When I read the data, I end up writing functions like this one:

```hs
whateverFromDB :: [SqlValue] -> Whatever
whateverFromDB (a:b:c:d:_) = Whatever (fromSql a) (fromSql b) (fromSql c) (fromSql d)
```

(I'm ommiting handling errors for the sake of clarity.)

Writing functions like these is really annoing and feels like creating a lot of boilerplate. Is there a more idiomatic way to convert a group of SqlValues into a Haskell data?

Comment: What SQL library are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any standard way in the `HDBC` library for this. If you're feeling particularly keen, you can roll your own machinery with [`GHC.Generics`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/GHC-Generics.html) for this, though the cure may be worse than the disease!

I also added the reverse conversion, but you can leave that out/split the classes if you want:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveAnyClass, DeriveGeneric, DefaultSignatures
           , TypeOperators, FlexibleContexts, FlexibleInstances
           , TypeSynonymInstances #-}

import Data.Convertible
import Database.HDBC


import Data.Coercible -- not strictly necessary
import GHC.Generics

-- serialization for Generic Rep-resentations
class GSqlConvert f where
    gFromSqlValuesImpl :: [SqlValue] -> (f a, [SqlValue])
    gToSqlValuesImpl :: f a -> [SqlValue] -> [SqlValue]

-- no data, no representation
instance GSqlConvert U1 where
    gFromSqlValuesImpl vs = (U1, vs)
    gToSqlValuesImpl U1 vs = vs

-- multiple things are stored in order
instance (GSqlConvert a, GSqlConvert b) => GSqlConvert (a :*: b) where
    gFromSqlValuesImpl vs =
        let (a, vs1) = gFromSqlValuesImpl vs
            (b, vs2) = gFromSqlValuesImpl vs1
         in (a :*: b, vs2)
    gToSqlValuesImpl (a :*: b) = gToSqlValuesImpl a . gToSqlValuesImpl b

-- note no instance for a :+: b, so no support for unions

-- ignore metadata
instance GSqlConvert a => GSqlConvert (M1 i c a) where
    gFromSqlValuesImpl = coerce . gFromSqlValuesImpl
    gToSqlValuesImpl = gToSqlValuesImpl . unM1

-- delegate to the members' serializers
instance SqlConvert a => GSqlConvert (K1 i a) where
    gFromSqlValuesImpl = coerce . fromSqlValuesImpl
    gToSqlValuesImpl = toSqlValuesImpl . unK1

-- serialization for normal data types
-- some types are "primitive" and have their own serialization code
-- other types are serialized via the default implementations,
-- which are based on Generic
-- the defaults convert the data into a generic representation and let
-- the GSqlConvert class decide how to serialize the generic representation
class SqlConvert a where
    fromSqlValuesImpl :: [SqlValue] -> (a, [SqlValue])
    default fromSqlValuesImpl :: (Generic a, GSqlConvert (Rep a))
                              => [SqlValue] -> (a, [SqlValue])
    fromSqlValuesImpl vs =
        let (rep, vs1) = gFromSqlValuesImpl vs
         in (to rep, vs1)

    toSqlValuesImpl :: a -> [SqlValue] -> [SqlValue]
    default toSqlValuesImpl :: (Generic a, GSqlConvert (Rep a))
                            => a -> [SqlValue] -> [SqlValue]
    toSqlValuesImpl a vs = gToSqlValuesImpl (from a) vs

fromSqlValuesImplPrim :: Convertible SqlValue a
                      => [SqlValue] -> (a, [SqlValue])
-- no error checking
fromSqlValuesImplPrim (v:vs) = (fromSql v, vs)

toSqlValuesImplPrim :: Convertible a SqlValue
                    => a -> [SqlValue] -> [SqlValue]
toSqlValuesImplPrim a vs = toSql a:vs

instance SqlConvert Int where
    fromSqlValuesImpl = fromSqlValuesImplPrim
    toSqlValuesImpl = toSqlValuesImplPrim
instance SqlConvert String where
    fromSqlValuesImpl = fromSqlValuesImplPrim
    toSqlValuesImpl = toSqlValuesImplPrim

fromSqlValues :: SqlConvert t => [SqlValue] -> t
 -- no error checking for unused values
fromSqlValues = fst . fromSqlValuesImpl

toSqlValues :: SqlConvert t => t -> [SqlValue]
toSqlValues v = toSqlValuesImpl v []

-- and now given all the above machinery, the conversion
-- for Whatever comes for free:
data Whatever = Whatever Int Int String String
    deriving (Show, Generic, SqlConvert)

{-
-- DeriveGeneric produces:
instance Generic Whatever where
  type Rep Whatever = D1 _ (C1 _ (
                            (S1 _ (Rec0 Int) :*: S1 _ (Rec0 Int))
                        :*: (S1 _ (Rec0 String) :*: S1 _ (Rec0 String))
                      ))
  to = _; from = _
-- There is an instance for GSqlConvert (Rep Whatever)
-- DeriveAnyClass produces
instance SqlConvert Whatever where
-- DefaultSignatures uses the default implementations from the class declaration
-- to implement the methods
   fromSqlValuesImpl = _; toSqlValuesImpl = _
-}
```

Comment: In my learning of Haskell I haven't yet reached the Generics. I need to lear nose more to understand your code.

For a simple app this seems like an overkill. I think it would pay off in a bigger thing, as the number of data types persisted grows.